# Which of the components based on the same RMS current given below is the most expensive?

Tags: power-electronics, components

Which of the components based on the same RMS current given below is the most expensive?

1. Diode
2. Triac
3. Thyristor

When I searched for this question on the Internet, I found close results and because I am not sure, I wanted to ask you. Since triac is a circuit element consisting of two reverse connected thyristors, do you think the correct answer should be triac?

Comment: You can't define a component based only on a current rating (even then, are you referring to maximum, peak, full duty cycle vs pulse, etc.). Other specifications such as maximum voltage, voltage drop, operating and storage temperature ranges, power ratings, switching times, etc. are needed to fully define the device before price comparisons can be made.

Comment: The question is a bit silly in that the components don't do the same job so comparing prices is of no practical use. A triac may be cheaper than a thyristor, for example, because of volume manufacturing. In any case all you need to do is use a parametric component selector for each component type on any of the major distributor sites and sort by price. Try Digi-Key, Farnell, RS, etc.

Comment: This question, by the way, is an exam question. Since I was not sure in the exam, I asked you :)

Comment: @laplace34 It's a terrible exam question. I wouldn't really believe anything your instructor says after thinking that is an okay question.

Answer (score 2):

A triac is the most complex, so this is probably the answer that your instructor wants.

However, as people have said in the comments, other factors could easily be more influential. Example: for current ranges used in household dimmers, huge quantities are produced and this may cause the triac to be the cheapest.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer wanted is that the TRIAC 'should be' more expensive because it is a more complex device that 'should be' more difficult to manufacture. Looking at the [theoretical construction](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/triac.html) you would think so, because it appears to be made from 2 SCRs wired back-to-back.

[image]

In [practice](https://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Ebart/book/book/chapter5/ch5_9.htm#5_9_3) however the entire device is built on a single slice of silicon just like an SCR, using the same processes. It might need a bit more area for the same current rating, and perhaps an extra diffusion layer, which 'could' raise the cost of the die a little.

[image]

But for power devices the package is often a much larger cost factor, and course economy of scale makes a huge difference too. A typical TRIAC used in consumer products might be cheaper simply due to the bigger demand for a bidirectional device, while in the high power industrial market SCRs might be cheaper.